# How to make a Maven plugin Mojo parameter's default value an empty string?

Tags: java, maven, mojo

How can a Maven plugin Mojo parameter be configured so that the default value is an empty String?

The `defaultValue` property of the `Parameter` annotation already defaults to `""`, so configuring the parameter like `@Parameter(defaultValue = "")` is equivalent to not configuring it at all.

This does not work and produces a null value at runtime:

```java
    @Parameter(defaultValue = "")
    public String myParam;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field can be initialized with an empty string to avoid a null value at runtime, while still allowing the user to override it:

```java
    @Parameter
    public String myParam = "";
```

The only caveat appears to be that this will not appear in documentation generated by the site plugin as a default value